# Bootstrap content isn't exapanding with data

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The last input is being hidden by the content, I am using twitter bootstrap. I'm sure I have the class row, and col in the correct place?

It's just a simple col with forms and inputs.

Is there anything you can see that would suggest why it's not expandingbecause col should expand with data if I use row which I am

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h5><?php echo System::translate("Your Products"); ?></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <form id="form" action="#" class="wizard-big">    
                <input type="hidden" name="add_product" value="1">
                <h1><?php echo System::translate('Product Information'); ?></h1>
                <fieldset>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Name'); ?></label>
                                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Condition'); ?></label>
                                <select name="condition" class="col-sm-6 form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="new"><?php echo System::translate("New"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="likenew"><?php echo System::translate("Like New"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="used"><?php echo System::translate("Used"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="spares"><?php echo System::translate("For parts or not working"); ?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Auction Type'); ?></label>
                                <select name="type" id="auctiontype" class="col-sm-6 form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="auction"><?php echo System::translate("Auction"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="buyitnow"><?php echo System::translate("Buy It now"); ?></option>    
                                </select> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="buyitnow">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                    <label><?php echo System::translate('Buy it now Price'); ?></label>
                                    <input required="" value="<?php echo System::escape(Request::post('price')); ?>" type="text" value="0" name="price" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="auctioninfo">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                    <label><?php echo System::translate('Starting Price'); ?></label>
                                    <input value="<?php echo System::escape(Request::post('startingprice')); ?>" name="startingprice" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Listing Duration'); ?></label>
                                <select name="type" name="auctionlength" id="auctionlength" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="3"><?php echo System::translate("3 Days"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="7"><?php echo System::translate("7 Days"); ?></option>   
                                    <option value="14"><?php echo System::translate("14 Days"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="30"><?php echo System::translate("30 Days"); ?></option>
                                </select> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Short Description'); ?></label>
                                <input id="shortdescription" name="shortdescription" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Description'); ?></label>
                                <textarea id="description" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle in which the problem is reproduced? From your code alone I cannot see anything that could "hide" input (fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to strictly put the elements with `col-sm-*` classes as children of elements with `row` classes. See the class  `buyitnow` for example

```
<div class="row">
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="buyitnow">
     <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
```

it should be something like this

```
<div class="row">
  .
  .
  .
  <div class="buyitnow col-sm-3">
     <div class="form-group">
```

and so on, the next code is a better formatted version of your code so you get the idea better

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h5><?php echo System::translate("Your Products"); ?></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <form id="form" action="#" class="wizard-big">    
                <input type="hidden" name="add_product" value="1">
                <h1><?php echo System::translate('Product Information'); ?></h1>
                <fieldset>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Name'); ?></label>
                                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Condition'); ?></label>
                                <select name="condition" class="col-sm-6 form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="new"><?php echo System::translate("New"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="likenew"><?php echo System::translate("Like New"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="used"><?php echo System::translate("Used"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="spares"><?php echo System::translate("For parts or not working"); ?></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Auction Type'); ?></label>
                                <select name="type" id="auctiontype" class="col-sm-6 form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="auction"><?php echo System::translate("Auction"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="buyitnow"><?php echo System::translate("Buy It now"); ?></option>    
                                </select> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="buyitnow col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><?php echo System::translate('Buy it now Price'); ?></label>
                                    <input required="" value="<?php echo System::escape(Request::post('price')); ?>" type="text" value="0" name="price" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="auctioninfo col-sm-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><?php echo System::translate('Starting Price'); ?></label>
                                    <input value="<?php echo System::escape(Request::post('startingprice')); ?>" name="startingprice" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true"> 
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Listing Duration'); ?></label>
                                <select name="type" name="auctionlength" id="auctionlength" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                                    <option value="3"><?php echo System::translate("3 Days"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="7"><?php echo System::translate("7 Days"); ?></option>   
                                    <option value="14"><?php echo System::translate("14 Days"); ?></option>
                                    <option value="30"><?php echo System::translate("30 Days"); ?></option>
                                </select> 
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Short Description'); ?></label>
                                <input id="shortdescription" name="shortdescription" type="text" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                                <label><?php echo System::translate('Product Description'); ?></label>
                                <textarea id="description" class="form-control required error" aria-required="true"></textarea>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
```